# BeautifulSoup extract html key words (Indeed)

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the the job total from this HTML using BeautifulSoup, with the following code and cannot text from the string with the error at the bottom:

Code

```
 page = requests.get(URL)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')  #.text
 print(soup.prettify())

 html = soup.prettify("utf-8")

 findJobs = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'jobtitle turnstileLink', 'title' :True})
 for findJob in findJobs:   
         print (findJob['title'])
```

HTML code

```
<a class="jobtitle turnstileLink" data-tn-element="jobTitle" href="/pagead/clk? 
mo=r&amp;ad=44-==&amp;vjs=3&amp;p=6&amp;sk=&amp;fvj=1" id="sja6" 
onclick="setRefineByCookie([]); sjoc('sja6',1); convCtr('SJ')" 
onmousedown="sjomd('sja6'); clk('sja6');" rel="noopener nofollow" 
target="_blank" title="Student Mentor">Student Mentor</a>
```

Error Message

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: What's the line number for that error?

Answer (score 0):

```
findJobs = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'jobtitle turnstileLink', 'title' :True})
for findJob in findJobs:   
    print (findJob['title'])
```

- you need to find `a` rather than `span`.
- `soup.findAll` will return list. You should operate with it as list.

---

Update 20180911:

I test it using

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<a class="jobtitle turnstileLink" data-tn-element="jobTitle" href="/pagead/clk? 
mo=r&amp;ad=44-==&amp;vjs=3&amp;p=6&amp;sk=&amp;fvj=1" id="sja6" 
onclick="setRefineByCookie([]); sjoc('sja6',1); convCtr('SJ')" 
onmousedown="sjomd('sja6'); clk('sja6');" rel="noopener nofollow" 
target="_blank" title="Student Mentor">Student Mentor</a>
"""

# page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')  #.text
print(soup.prettify())

html = soup.prettify("utf-8")

findJobs = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'jobtitle turnstileLink', 'title' :True})
for findJob in findJobs:   
     print (findJob['title']) 
# Output: Student Mentor
```

It runs correctly. Is somewhere missed?

Comment: Many thanks, but I still get the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

Comment: @BrendonShaw sure? could you paste your code after modification?

Comment: @BrendonShaw I pasted my test code, it run normally. Is somewhere I missed?

Comment: Many thanks, I cut out a read from the page and only put in the string to decode. I need to read the complete page and then extract the string from the HTML page.